# completion and returning value

Tags: swift, completionhandler

i'm struggling with this piece of code. I'm trying to return json data i got from api link. I read several other questions but i didn't find out to make it work. All the playground code is here. Thanks in advance !

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

struct WebsiteDescription: Decodable {
    let ETH: Devise
}
struct Devise: Decodable {
    let EUR : Double
}

func refreshPrices(DeLaDevise nom: String, completion: @escaping ((Double) -> Double)) -> Void {

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=" + nom + "&tsyms=EUR") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, reponse, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        var prix: Double = 0.0
        print(data)
        do {
            let website = try JSONDecoder().decode(WebsiteDescription.self, from: data)
            prix = website.ETH.EUR
            completion(prix)
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print(jsonErr)
        }
        }.resume()
    }

   refreshPrices(DeLaDevise: "ETH") { prix in
            print(prix)
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.

It seems paradox but the closure does **not** return something, it passes a parameter.

The error message gives you a precise clue:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Double'

Just change the return value to `Void` aka `()`

```
func refreshPrices(DeLaDevise nom: String, completion: @escaping (Double) -> ()) -> Void {
```

Comment: thanks, it prints the price ! but now if i want to get that price outside the function, i wrote `prixFinal = prix` inside the function refreshPrices (i created the variable before the function) and then if i print it after the function refreshPrices it doesn't work !

Comment: Face the fact that `dataTask` works asynchronously. Process the value inside the closure, that's the purpose of a completion handler.

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain myself very well, when i said inside the function, it was in the second part at the end of the code `refreshPrices(DeLaDevise: "ETH") { prix in prixFinal = prix }`

Comment: I did understand but it seems you don't. *asynchronously* means that the closure (completion handler) is executed much later than the next line after the call of `refreshPrices(DeLaDevise: "ETH") ...`. So what you need to do with `prix` do it inside the closure.

Comment: Oh ok i got it, so if i want to store to display it later and do some stuff in between it wont work as the closure will be executed at the end ?